# Validar que CKEDITOR no este vacio

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

estoy utilizando CKEDITOR 5 para sustituir unos textarea que servirán para publicación de contenido informativo en un sitio web. El problema lo tengo al momento de validar que el CKEDITOR no este vació, he intentado varias cosas pero nada que puedo dar con la solución. Lo que tengo realizado es lo siguiente:

```
document.querySelector( '#btn_noticia' ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
  var DataNoticia = editor_noticia.getData();
  if(DataNoticia==""){
    alert("Debes escribir algo en el editor para publicar");
  }else{
    $("#btn_noticia").attr("disabled",true).text("Publicando...");
    $.post('ajax.php?mode=nueva_noticia',{contenido_noti:DataNoticia},function(r){
        if (r==1) {
            $.notify({
                icon: 'font-icon font-icon-check-circle',
                title: '<strong>Noticia publicada</strong>',
                message: ''
            },{
                type: 'success'
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
                location.reload();
            },2000);
        }else{
            alert(r);
            $("#btn_noticia").attr("disabled",false).text("Publicar");
        }
    })
  }
});
```

Con esto asi el CKEDITOR este vacio me publica el contenido, lo mas cerca que estuve fue colocando esto en el condicional

```
if($("#contenido_noti iframe").contents().find("body").text()=="")
```

Con esto si me valida cuando esta vació, pero aun así el CKEDITOR tenga texto me sigue diciendo que esta vació. Sigo intentando y nada que doy con la solución.

Comment: Esta seguro que esta utilizando el selector correcto para acceder a su iframe?

Answer (score 2):

La solucion la he encontrado de la siguiente manera:

He hecho un `console.log(DataNoticia)` y el CKEDITOR cuando esta vació muestra lo siguiente `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.

Y la el condicional a quedado asi:

```
var DataNoticia = editor_noticia.getData();
if(DataNoticia=="<p>&nbsp;</p>"){
    alert("Debes llenar ambos campos");
    return false;
}else{
 ///
}
```